# Where IN for linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have seen questions with this subject but mine is different.

i have stored procedure (EmpsByManager) imported in EF. it returns data of following fields:

`EmpId`, `EmpName`, `PrimaryMobile`

I have a `claimTable` in the db having the following fields

`EmpId`, `ClaimId`, `ClaimDetails`...

I want to return all claims from the `claimTable` `IN` the `Employees` of `EmpsByManager(ManagerId)`

I could manage to do this with a loop:

```
public dynamic getActiveClaims(int ManagerId)
        {
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

            var myEmps = db.getEmpDetofManager(ManagerId).ToList();

            List<List<claimJSON>> claimsList = new List<List<claimJSON>>();

            foreach(var Emp in myEmps)
            {
                claimsList.Add(db.claimJSONs.Where(e => e.EmpId == Emp.EmpId && e.claimstatus != 0 && e.claimstatus != 8).ToList());
            }

            return claimsList;
        }
```

This is giving correct results but, I myself am not convinced with the complexity and number of database hits to get the required result.

Anyone? Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are hitting the db everytime inside your loop. You can replace the Where clause inside your `foreach` loop with  the use of the `Contains()` method.

```
var myEmps = db.getEmpDetofManager(ManagerId).ToList();

// Get all EmpIds from the result and store to a List of Int

List<int> empIds = myEmps.Select(f=>f.EmpId).ToList();

// Use the List of EmpId's in your LINQ query.

var claimsList  = db.claimJSONs.Where(e => empIds.Contains(e.EmpId) 
                             && e.claimstatus != 0 && e.claimstatus != 8).ToList();
```

Also, not that the result in `claimsList` variable will be a `List<claimJSON>` , not `List<List<claimJSON>>>`

This will result in 2 hits to the db. One for the stored proc and another for getting data from the claimJSON table for the list of EmpIds we got from the stored proc result.

Comment: , `List<int>` had to be changed to ` IEnumerable<int>`. The above code worked. thanks

Comment: or you can use `var` and let compiler infer the type. anyway i changed the code to convert the `IEnumerable` to `List`. Both will work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is not a lot you CAN optimize. The main problem is the stored procedure.

As you can not join - even without the limitations of EF - the output of a stored procedure... no, you have no way. Not without rewriting the SP. Which should not be there anyway - this functionality is much better suited for a function which can then be used in a more complex query style. Someone forced that into a SP - and now you have to live with the limitations.